# Создание функций с помощью макросов

Tags: c++, c, макросы

Как создать макрос PROPERTY, который бы можно использовать следующим образом:

```
#define PROPERTY(config_type, property_name, childs, ...)
...

class BaseConfig
{
public:
    PROPERTY("int", "name", "child1", "child1_1")
    PROPERTY("float", "name2", "child2",)
};
```

Который бы разворачивался в следующий класс:

```
class BaseConfig
{
public:
    int name()
    {
        ...
    }
    float name2()
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Внутри функций мне надо получить childs.

Comment: напишите полностью тело ожидаемых функций.

Comment: @KoVadim Мне бы хотелось создать простой интерфейс для получения данных из xml file, сейчас это делается c gjследующим образом:
class BaseConfig{
public:
    int num_source(){
        tinyxml2::XMLHandle xml_handle(this->config);
        xml_handle.FirstChildElement("config").
                FirstChildElement("common").
                FirstChildElement("num_source").ToElement()->IntText();
    }
};

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону использования xpath (TinyXPath), можно будет передавать путь к дочернему элементу одной строкой. Или данное применение дано только для примера, и цель именно научиться обрабатывать множественные аргументы в define?

Comment: @Chorkov  Цель была упрастить создание новой структуры для парсинга xml файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макрос написать можно, но есть две проблемы - variadic macros и тип возвращаемого значения. Но... кто нам мешает написать макрос под наши задачи? Предлагаю для начала сделать просто два макроса

```
#define INT_PROPERTY1(config_type, property_name, childs) \
    int property_name() { \
       tinyxml2::XMLHandle xml_handle(this->config); \
       xml_handle.FirstChildElement(#childs).FindFirstChild(#property_name).ToElement()->IntText();\
    } \

#define INT_PROPERTY2(config_type, property_name, childs1, childs2) \
    int property_name() { \
       tinyxml2::XMLHandle xml_handle(this->config); \
       xml_handle.FirstChildElement(#childs1).FirstChildElement(#childs2).FindFirstChild(#property_name).ToElement()->IntText();\
    } \
```

да, можно и дальше продолжать, но как по мне - этого уже хватит на много. А если добавить строки - вообще будет отлично.

Следующим этапом должно быть написание макроса, который получает конечную функцию (IntText) и подставляет, что бы не дублировать.

Но как мне кажется, тут лучше написать парочку шаблонов.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно с помощью VA_ARGS сделать динамически на любое число параметров, а потом в цикле вызывать FirstChildElement? А если через шаблоны делать, то не понятно что в качестве аргумента брать?

Comment: да, я думал через VA_ARGS, это даже не сложно, нужна будет только дополнительная функция, которая будет принимать в том или ином виде список нод.

Comment: Компилятор gcc  выдает ошибку : '#' is not followed by a macro parameter .

Comment: А вызываете так `PROPERTY("float", "name2", "child2")` или так `PROPERTY(float, name2, child2)`

Comment: Cпасибо. Вызывал первым вариантом.

Comment: Я поторопился с выводом, ошибка осталась + name2, child2  "has not been declared" пишет.

Comment: Макросы отлично принимают va_args, `#define FUNC(a,b,...) a(b->child, __VA_ARGS__)` например..